# Log4j2 fatjar programmatically config

Tags: java, gradle, logging, log4j2, fatjar

I'm trying to get log4j2 work within a fatjar.
When running in intellij every works fine, but when building my fatjar an running it like

```
java -jar dx.jar
```

only errors are logged to console, and  nothing to the rollingfile. It seams ignoring my config.

Configuration:

```
        String logFile = logPath + "dxpos.log";
        String logFilePattern = logPath + "dxpos-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log";

        LogManager.shutdown();

        var builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

        var layout = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n");

        var console = builder.newAppender("console", "Console")
                .addAttribute("target", "SYSTEM_OUT")
                .addAttribute("immediateFlush", true)
                .add(layout);

        var triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
                .addComponent(builder.newComponent("TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy"))
                .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "100M"));
        var rollingFile = builder.newAppender("rollingFile", "RollingFile")
                .addAttribute("fileName", logFile)
                .addAttribute("filePattern", logFilePattern)
                .addAttribute("immediateFlush", true)
                .addAttribute("append", true)
                .addComponent(triggeringPolicy)
                .add(layout);

        var rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(Level.INFO)
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef("console"))
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef("rollingFile"));

        builder.add(console);
        builder.add(rollingFile);
        builder.add(rootLogger);
        
        Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
```

Comment: Can you see if the class exists in your .jar file?  Simply rename to .zip and find it.
IF it does exist, perhaps your configuration is profile based? and when running java -jar you are using the default profile?

Comment: The class exists. What do you mean with profile? It's not a spring boot application it's a swing application

Answer (score 0):

After searching a file I a switch from programmatically config method to XML

To getting it to work you have to declare the logger

```
public static Logger logger = null;
```

Add some variables like that

```
MDC.put("logFile", logFile);
MDC.put("LogFilePattern", logFilePattern);
```

And create the logger

```
logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainForm.class);
```